# Where to do CMS-type URL handling - htaccess or index.php?

Tags: .htaccess

In my application, I have wikis blogs and other content where the author can assign a URL when creating them so that is is optimized for search engines.

So, I want to redirect the URLs to index.php where I check against the database and generate the output accordingly.

But, there are also requests for CSS, images and other files which I have to leave alone.

- I can either exclude CSS, images etc in HTACCESS and redirect everything else to index.php.
- Or I can redirect everything to index.php and then simply change back the location using header() for images css etc..

Which method should I go for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about only handing any resource file/directory request that doesn't exist off to your `index.php` file? I think that's usually how these things work.

**.htaccess** -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Great! I assume -f and -d mean 'an exising file' and 'an existing directory'.. ??

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my application is include everything non-template related in a header.php file and everything template-related in a footer.php file. That way, I can call header.php should I need access to /just/ database aspects of my software.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is much better to exclude static files (css, js, images) using simple .htaccess rules and forward only rest of URIs to your front controller i.e. `index.php`.

If you were to handle those static files in your `index.php` then you will have to either redirect them using php `header()` function (and add 1 extra round-trip to browser) OR you will need to output their content using appropriate content type not really the job your front controller should be doing..